# Ghostscript: print only last page of batch of files

Tags: batch-file, pdf, count, ghostscript, pdftk

I would like to print only the last page of a batch of .pdf-files on Windows command and combine them.

The page count of each .pdf-file varies.

I can determine the last page with

```
gs -q -c "(file.pdf) (r) file runpdfbegin pdfpagecount =" -f file.pdf
```

But how can they be printed and combined with Ghostscript?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot simply say 'LastPage' you need to run each file individually and alter FirstPage and LastPage between each one. I haven't tried it but something like:

```
gs -dFirstPage=10 -dLastPage=10 file1.pdf -dFirstPage=2 -dLastPage=2 file2.pdf....
```

might work. Of course you will need to get FirstPage and LastPage correct for each file. This almost certainly won't work in future versions though because the action of FirstPage and LastPage is changing. You will need a different approach when that work is complete.

You *could* write a PostScript program which opened each of a group of PDF files, determined the last page in each (using the code you already have) and the set FirstPage and LastPage before executing the file again to render it.

Answer (score 1):

This answer is not using Ghostscript, but `pdftk`.

For the task at hand, this is the better tool to use. **Example command:**

```
pdftk             \
    A=file1.pdf   \
    B=file2.pdf   \
    C=file3.pdf   \
  cat             \
    Aend          \
    Bend          \
    Cend          \
  output          \
    result.pdf
```

This uses 2 little tricks available when running `pdftk`:

1. *'handles'* `A`, `B` and `C` for `file1.pdf`, `file2.pdf` and `file3.pdf`
2. the `end` keyword attached to the handles to indicate the last page.

`pdftk` handles could be used to indicate a *page range*, such as `C4-6` (meaning pages 4-6 of `file3.pdf`), or `Bodd` (meaning all odd pages of `file2.pdf`).

Find more options by looking at the output of `pdftk --help`.

Typically, using `pdftk` for this particular type of job is significantly faster than using Ghostscript.

If you *need* to use Ghostscript for its other features (i.e. that it basically constructs a completely new PDF file every single time it writes PDF output), you can still run `result.pdf` through Ghostscript. My guess is that even the combined times of the `pdftk` + `gs` runs will be lower than letting `gs` do all the work alone.